# SelectedItemChanged event for WPF custom TreeView control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

C#, WPF. I have subclassed the TreeView control and cannot get the `SelectedItemChanged` event working. I don't see what I am doing differently from examples such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756011/changing-wpf-treeview-selecteditem-in-selecteditemchanged-event) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditemchanged?view=netcore-3.1).

Code will run but at `InitializeComponent()` I get the following error:

> ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its
>   signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the
>   delegate type.

This minimal project demonstrates the problem:

```
<Window x:Class="TEST.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:TEST"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Grid>
    <custom:CustomTreeView x:Name ="treeViewConfig2" 
      SelectedItemChanged="TreeViewControl_SelectedItemChanged" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
namespace TEST
{
    /// <summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //CustomTreeView tree = new CustomTreeView();
        }
    }

    public class CustomTreeView : TreeView
    {
        public CustomTreeView() { } // default constructor

        private void TreeViewControl_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if it could be something to do with the `<object SelectedItemChanged="RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler"/>` mentioned in the Microsoft documentation but I don't know where/how I would implement this, and am not seeing anything equivalent in other examples.

Making the event `public` doesn't change behaviour.

Comment: TreeViewControl_SelectedItemChanged should be in MainWindow class

Answer (score 0):

The problem was just caused by putting the event handler in the wrong class. Thanks to ASh who pointed this out in a comment. For the benefit of others, this is working code:

```
<Window x:Class="TEST.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:TEST"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Grid>
    <custom:CustomTreeView x:Name ="treeViewConfig2" 
      SelectedItemChanged="TreeViewControl_SelectedItemChanged" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CustomTreeView tree = new CustomTreeView();
    }
    private void TreeViewControl_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((string)e.NewValue + " was selected");
    }
}

public class CustomTreeView : TreeView
{
    public CustomTreeView() {
        Items.Add("Item 1");
        Items.Add("Item 2");
    }

}
```